# Ubuntu 18.04 nothing shows on my desktop after minimizing a window or using the super key once

Tags: gnome-shell

Okay the title sucks, English isn't my first language so be patient please.
Alright, as of today I am experiencing a very strange issue.

I can login fine, everything shows up as it should. I can access the menus with the superkey and open whatever application that I want to.

But as soon as I minimize the application, open the contextual menu with the superkey or just alt tab, everything disappears. No way to go back to the menus, open an application or alt tab into anything. I have to logout and login again. At which point I can open the menus once and it starts all over again as soon as I minimize or access the menus. Clicking on the top panel does work though, I can log out by using the top right corner click with no problem.

So far, I have booted with an older kernel, reinstalled gnome-shell and gnome-desktop, turned off all extensions. Still, I can't find a way to fix it.

I need to point out that I can start an application from the terminal and it runs in the background. The OS seems to be working fine on that front. I just can't make anything appear on the screen.

I have reset the workspaces to default, tried dynamic and only one workspace, to no avail.

My google-fu failed me because I have no idea what to type in the search bar.

Please help

Comment: Question not entirely clear. Is your keyboard frozen, or does your screen turn black ('everything disappears'), or both? That "everything disappears" sounds like an issue with your graphics drivers to me. You may want to clarify your problem and add system information to your question,